# Access MVC Model property that is already JSON in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc, chart.js

Disclaimer: I do not want to encode/Serialize the property/object in the view! I want to to this in my business layer and send it to the controller.

I have a list of CustomerDetailViewModels that i want to show in CustomerDetailView. it looks like this:

```
   public class CustomerDetailViewModel
{
    public CustomerDetailViewModel()
    {
        EmployeeAndHours = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }

    public string customerName { get; set; }
    public string projectName { get; set; }
    public int totalNumberOfProjectHours { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> EmployeeAndHours { get; set; }
    public string jsonChartDataSets { get; set; }
}
```

So i will iterate through them and show them in a table. Now, the 'jsonChartDatasets' is a property that is filled from list of objects and that i serialize like this: 'JsonConvert.SerializeObject(listOfDatasets);'
It looks like this :
[image]

every 'jsonChartDataSets looks the same. It dosent matter. What matters is that i have a script in the view where I want to use this json string. Its for ChartJS.

It looks like this, and this is how Ive tried to use the property:

```js
var months = ['Januari', 'Februari', 'Mars', 'April', 'Maj', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'Augusti', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'December'];

// For drawing the lines
var ctx = document.getElementById("projectChart");

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: months,
        datasets: '@Model[0].jsonChartDataSets'
    },
    options:
    {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true
    }
});
```

These are the errors (the topmost one is a console.log of ('@Model[0].jsonChartDataSets').

I Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `jsonChartDataSets` property is a `string`, not json. You need to convert it back again in your script using `JSON.parse()`.

Note you also need `@inject IJsonHelper Json;` in your view for the `Json.Serialize()` method.

```
// Get the value from the model
var data = @Json.Serialize(@Model[0].jsonChartDataSets);
// convert to javascript array
data = JSON.parse(data);

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: months,
        datasets: data
    },
    ....
});
```